# Can you use a dictionary with a let statement in Iqueryable with Entity framework core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

So what I am trying to do is write code that will pick an appropriate personnel based on the data that I have to submit a license to a district board. This code is obfuscated from my actual codebase so please bear with the student/class example.

The logic should say, if there was no teacher present, or teacher has no license then use the state school directors license. if we cant find that, use the national.

The fall back works fine when I exclude the state director from the query, it runs without problem. However, when I try to include this, it throws a 'System.InvalidOperationException'. I have verified that all students have a current address and an appropriate state exists in the dictionary.

It looks like my current syntax of using a dictionary in an iqueryable is invalid and EF doesnt know how to work with a dictionary!

```
 var qry = from student in FilteredContext // type is IQueryable<Student>
  let studentsAddress = student.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.IsCurrent)
  
  let instructor = lastClass == null ? : lastClass.Instructor
  let stateSchoolDirector = _personnelContext.Context.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ID == SchoolDirectors.ByState[currentAddress.State])
  let nationalSchoolDirector = _personnelContext.Context.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == SchoolDirectors.NationalSchoolDirector)
  
  let personnelForLicense = instructor ?? stateSchoolDirector ?? national
  
  select personnelForLicense.License;
  
  var results = qry.ToList();
```

So my question is, is there any way to represent a dictionary or something like it within iqueryable? If not, are there any reasonable work arounds? I am totally stuck here and despite seraching could not easily find anything like it on StackOverflow or google results. The closest suggestion I could find was telling me to convert to .AsEnumerable() which I fail to see how it will work with my let statements

Comment: I do not see dictionary here. Yes query can be rewritten to translatable, but it is too obfuscated and I cannot understand all relations. `lastClass` from where it appear. `stateSchoolDirector`, `stateSchoolDirector `,  `national` also not. visible for analysis.

Comment: To clarify, the dictionary is Dictionary ByState[currentAddress.State]. Sorry for the confusion, but its a dictionary of key->string value->guid where the guid is a primary key on the personnel record

Comment: I found a bug in my code, aside from what I posted regarding dictionary lookup. since Instructor is a record, thus an object entity framework can not translate the null coalesce with an instance. It can only translate with SQL like objects. I am updating my code to ignore the null coalese and just call directly on stateSchoolDirector for the personnel. However, it is still erroring with InvalidOperation because of the dictionary lookup

Comment: Ha I cant!!! well it would read this if I could change it....
let personnelForLicense = /*instructor ??*/ stateSchoolDirector /*?? national*/

this code is obviously not right but it isolates to the issue I am trying to solve. I can get around the null coalescing with using ternary null checking though it is more ugly to read

Answer (score 0):

Just for going full circle, the only option that I could think of was to convert the dictionary into an actual SQL table/entity on the context